# Using pointer in heap for c++

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

I am learning the basics of C++ and came across this question as I was learning pointers. I understand that `*` is used to access the value of the address stored in the pointer. So if I were to do this:

```
int *p;
p = new int[5];
```

why is it that the second line would create an array in heap and store the address of the array in `p`? We did not dereference `p` in the second line by doing a `*p`. As far as my limited knowledge tells me, doing `p=value` would be storing that value in the pointer `p` when we are supposed to store the address of that value in the pointer `p`.

Comment: In an expression, `*` is used to access *the value stored **at that** address,*  not the value **of the** address. In you example, `p` is an address, and you access the "value of that address" by simply saying `p`. E.g. if you want to print that address:  `printf("%p\n", (void *)p);`. (The cast to void * is just a formal necessity.) In order to print the integer *stored at* the address `p`,: `printf("%d\n", *p);`.

Comment: if you do this, then you are doing something wrong.First you should use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays and then if the size is constant `5` there is no reason to allocate dynamically. For your question: `new` does return an adress

Comment: Oh, and whether the pointer points to the heap, the stack, or to a global variable is irrelevant. The important thing is that if you assign to `p` the right side must be an address, which is what `new` returns. If you assign to `*p`, by contrast, the right side must be an integer.

Comment: `int* p; p = new int;` and `int* p; p = new int[5];` show how pointers and arrays have a close relationship.  That's part of C++'s C heritage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding pointers may be hard.

Suppose there's a house, at "GreatStreet no 234". Nobody knows about this house.

Now person A, who lives somewhere else, is told about that house. The information is just the address of the house. There's a plus in the info: it says "it's a house, no other thing".

Same goes with pointers.

```
int *p;
p = new int[5];
```

`int *p` is person A. At this moment he knows nothing, except that latter it will be informed about a house. That it is related to a house and not to a car is due to `int`. A car would be `float` instead.

`int[5]` is the house, freshly built by `new` action. This `new` command not only creates the array, but it also returns the address, this is "GreatStreet no 234" (or its equivalent in heap position).

`p= new...` tells person A about the address of the house.

The good thing with pointers is that not only you can work with "person A" (by `p`) but also with its info about the house (by the asterisk in `*p`).

So, you can change the house if you use the asterisk method (dereference) `*p = 3`. But you can not change the address of the house.

If you change the info of the pointer `p= ...` without asterisk, you're changing the address to another house.

Comment: `int A[5] = {5,3,2,1,2};` and `int *p = A;` For such a case, i am storing the address of A in pointer p right? So can i say that when declaring a pointer, i am not dereferencing with * but simply declaring that it is a pointer with *? Thanks for the help

Comment: @Shane Yes, `int* p` is a declaration "p is a pointer that will store the address of an int" Don't get confused about the asterisk close to the type or the identifyer (`int* p` vs `int *p`). It's the same, even with no space in between.

Answer (score 3):

> We did not dereference p in the second line by doing a *p.

Which is a good thing. On the first line, the pointer was not initialised, so it doesn't point to anything. Attempting to access the imaginary pointed object by indirecting through a pointer that doesn't point to an object results in undefined behaviour.

By assigning the pointer without indirecting through it, the pointer itself is is modified rather than the pointed object.

> As far as my limited knowledge tells me, doing a p=value would be storing that value in the pointer p

Which is exactly what we want to do, when that value is the address of an object.

---

P.S. The example leaks memory. Avoid using bare owning pointers. Use `std::vector` to create a dynamic array.